# Woudn't usage: Wouldn't vs didn't ,wouldn't vs will not, wouldn't vs doesn't

Tags: phrase-usage, auxiliary-verbs

Wouldn't usage has become very common in American English and in Novels? I spent a lot of time to understand the difference between wouldn't vs didn't, wouldn't vs will, and wouldn't vs don't. The more I try to understand, the more I am getting confused. Can someone explain this in detail? Below are the examples that sound the same when I replace wouldn't.
E.g.:

1. I wouldn't want to do it all over again.

   - 1a. I don't want to do it all over again.
2. He wouldn't like to fight with the bull.

   - 2a. He doesn't like to fight with the bull.
3. It wouldn't be the end of the world.

   - 3a. It's not the end of the world.
4. We'll have a vacation you wouldn't believe.

   - 4a. We'll have a vacation you will not believe.
5. Wouldn't you like It?

   - 5a. Didn't you like it?
6. I wouldn't do it.

   - 6a. I will not do it.

Comment: Related: [Usage of "will" and "would"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45132/usage-of-will-and-would)

Comment: Most of your examples use _would_ to refer to something hypothetical. 'I don't want to do it all over again' implies that there is a strong likelihood that you will have to do so. 'I wouldn't want to...' means 'Even if I was asked to, or had the chance to do it again, I would choose not to.' 'Wouldn't you like it?' refers to a possibility, 'Didn't you like it?' to something that has already happened.